# Is there a way to run parLapply on the GPU?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a number of scripts that uses parallel::parLapply() to parallelise data simulation and model fitting in lavaan. (see a sample piece of code below.)
It works as expected to use multiple CPU cores in parallel.

I wonder whether there is a not-too-complicated way for parLapply to use the GPU cores instead of the CPU. I presume this would make it much faster. (The computer in question has a NVidia 3070 ti installed.)

Thanks a lot!

```
# Load libraries
library(parallel)
library(lavaan)

# Number of simulated datasets
nsim <- 10000

# Parallel processing
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(
  parallel::detectCores()
)

# Create random seeds
seeds <- {set.seed(2738273); 
  (sample(x=1:1e7, size=nsim, replace=FALSE))}

# Data simulation
xyz <- parLapply(
  cl=cl, 
  X=seeds,
  fun=function(i){
    model <- '
    ...lavaan model code omitted for brevity...
    '
    lavaan::simulateData(
      model=model, 
      model.type="cfa", 
      meanstructure=TRUE, 
      sample.nobs=1000, 
      return.type="data.frame", 
      seed=i)
  })
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/308771/why-are-we-still-using-cpus-instead-of-gpus

Comment: I am not sure how this link answers the question, but thanks anyway.

Comment: GPU and CPU are different instruction sets, as such one cannot take executable code for a CPU and just send it to a GPU for execution. R runs on the CPU, period. There are particular things that can be sent to the GPU, including tensorflow and such, when you have the libraries and configuration to support it. But arbitrary R expressions/code cannot be sent to a GPU. Perhaps the link could have included a note to this effect, but the key point (per my comment) is *"CPUs and GPUs have significantly different architectures"*. AFAIK, there is no "R" running natively on a GPU.